# Saiku displays no result and does not display right numbers

Tags: analysis, pentaho

I am trying to produce a set of reports and dashboards using Pentaho BI Server. I installed the latest release of Saiku plugin (2.3) and it seemed to be working fine. However, I have a measure type `int` that used to give me an SQL query error, but I fixed it by setting the type to `BIGINT`. However, now the results that are displayed have nothing to do with the one in the database.
Also, I have a measure (type `int` too) named quantity that worked just fine when I created the report, but now once I click on it I get "no result". I could not find a solution to both problems, could you please provide me with a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the underlying database, and what version of the jdbc driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `*.mondrian.xml`? I believe you have to define the other elements of your report in the metadata layer. Try to create a Mondrian schema.